# pycharm remote interpeter unknown

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-debugging

server:windows7
cilent:windows10

i Configuring Remote Python Interpreters on cilent
the ssh connection is ok

when i click ok button it's shows that 'interpreter /usr/bin/python doesn't exist on remote server'

so i change the python interpreter path to the python.exe on the server
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFn9T.png)

after save over it's show that it's an unknown interpreter
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcayD.png)

and when i run my test python file it' shows 
unable to execute command or shell on remote system:Failed to Execute process

some one can tell me it's ssh permission problem or other setting problem?
thx

Comment: Please include your code and error messages as text in your question.

Comment: Could you show what your run configuration is like for your `Remote debugger`?